# unicode' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, solr, solr4, pysolr

I am updating the document in solr using pysolr python. I am taking one field data from solr document and after updating it i am ingesting it again using

```
solr.add(dict)
```

Basically  i am ingesting a dictionary in solr again.
However i am getting this error :

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysolr.py", line 907, in add
    el = self._build_doc(doc, boost=boost, fieldUpdates=fieldUpdates)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysolr.py", line 822, in _build_doc
    for key, value in doc.items():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Seems like you're passing a `string`, not a `dict` to the `add` method. You may want to check the type of your parameter

Comment: I checked the type its a dictionary <type 'dict'> only that i am passing.

Comment: The error message says otherwise. Are you adding multiple docs?

Comment: i have tried solr.add(res[dict]) instead of  solr.add(dict). It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried **solr.add(res[dict])** instead of **solr.add(dict)** It worked.